# how to perform operations on a subset of a dataset

Tags: probability-or-statistics, dataset, code-request, code-review

I have this data set:

```
rawdata = {{"time", "region", "subregion", "status", "country", 
"indicator", "data"}, {2000.`, "Africa", "Central Africa", "LDC", 
"Angola", "Remittances", 0.0267993914860461`}, {2000.`, "Africa", 
"Central Africa", "LDC", "Angola", "ODA", 
4.05719895987582`}, {2000.`, "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", 
"Bhutan", "Tax revenues", 12.9794732034214`}, {2000.`, "Asia", 
"South Asia", "ODC", "Bhutan", "Gross domestic savings", 
27.3167848363906`}, {2000.`, "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", 
"Bhutan", "Adjusted net savings", 44.1909199162357`}, {2000.`, 
"Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", "Solomon Islands", 
"Gross domestic savings", 0.221702694892883`}, {2000.`, "Asia", 
"SIDS", "LDC", "Kiribati", "Adjusted net savings", 7.9`}, {2001.`,
 "Africa", "Central Africa", "LDC", "Angola", "Remittances", 
0.0212549938881954`}, {2001.`, "Africa", "Central Africa", "LDC", 
"Angola", "ODA", 3.83358753594609`}, {2001.`, "Asia", 
"South Asia", "ODC", "Bhutan", "Tax revenues", 
12.5415621434496`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", 
"Bhutan", "Gross domestic savings", 37.1804901737896`}, {2001.`, 
"Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", "Bhutan", "Broadband subscriptions", 
0.497992844`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", "Solomon Islands", 
"Tax revenues", 4.7808499936`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", 
"Solomon Islands", "Gross domestic savings", 
0.38613349199295`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", "Kiribati", 
"Gross domestic savings", 7.9`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", 
"Kiribati", "Internet users", 8.6`}};
```

and

```
jdata = Join @@ 
Map[a \[Function] 
 Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ Rest[a]]][{rawdata}];
```

generates:

[image]

I want to calculate "percentage change" for a given country and a given indicator over the beginning and end years available. For example, for Bhutan percentage change in `Tax revenues` over period 2000-2001.

I tried other operations such as below:

```
jdata[All, {"time", "country", "data"}][All, "data"] // Mean
```

which is the mean value of all the data regardless of country and indicator.

This also gives me a result:

```
jdata[GroupBy["country"], Total[#] &, "data"]
```

which is the total of data (regardless of indicator) over the period 2000-2001. The percentage change calculation for individual countries should have the form:

```
jdata[GroupBy["country"], PercentageChange[Log[#2]-Log[#1]] &, "data"]
```

I cannot figure out how to do the percentage change in an indicator of a given country during a specific period of time (in my original data set, the time goes from 2000 to 2030), and in fact, I want to be able to select a subset within the entire time period.

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
jdata[GroupBy[{#country, #indicator} & -> Last]] // 
  Map[Quantity[100.*(Last@# - First@#)/First@#, "Percent"] &]
```

[image]

Should add `jdata // SortBy[#time &]` so the first and last values are correct. For specific date ranges add e.g. `Select[Between[#time, {2000, 2011}] &]`

Comment: I edited my question because I noticed that my data set is not the one I originally posted. Please see the edit for the dataset format. I want to calculate for example percentage change in indicator "EVI" and "Export concentration" and so on. Sorry for my mistake. I just gave a small part of the dataset.

Comment: The question is to calculate percentage change for a given country, for a given time period, for a selected indicator like "EVI". Of course, calculations should be made for all countries at once.

Comment: Can you show me how to use `Select[Between[#time, {2000, 2011}] &]` in the code you gave above?

Comment: Perform the `Select` before the `GroupBy`. `jdata[Select[Between[#time, {2000, 2011}] &]][
  GroupBy[{#country, #indicator} & -> Last]] // 
 Map[Quantity[100.*(Last@# - First@#)/First@#, "Percent"] &]`